# How to send the image from c or c++ to C# with pinvoke

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-c++

how to send a image file from C or C++ to C# with Pinvoke, if possible please paste the code...

from file pointer or some other pointer from C and how to cast and display the image in C# side.

Comment: Pinvoke is a feature that allows C# to call C or C++ code.  You are doing this the wrong way around.  Use COM or host the CLR to have a C++ program use .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

C#/VB uses bitmaps, so you have to convert it first.

for c++ with "fileapi.h"

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void MyFunct(HANDLE* fileHandle) 
{
    *fileHandle = CreateFile(MyBitmap, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
}
```

Usage for VB.Net

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("MyDll.dll")> _
Public Shared Sub MyFunct(ByRef fileHandle As IntPtr)
End Sub

Sub MyFunction()
    Dim picture As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim sFileHandle As Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle
    Dim FilePointer As IntPtr
    MyFunct(FilePointer)
    sFileHandle = New Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle(FilePointer, True)
    picture = Image.FromStream(New System.IO.FileStream(sFileHandle, IO.FileAccess.Read))
End Sub
```

This is a way without using Marshalling and PInvoke but it is "quick and dirty" so you have to handle the pointer and memory yourself...

Comment: Hi Beinfreiheit, can you please write it in C#, i am new to C# and i don't have any idea VB.

Comment: Hi, I got exception at picture = Image.FromStream(New System.IO.FileStream(sFileHandle, IO.FileAccess.Read)) , it says parameter is not valid.. and MyBitmap in CreateFile is a jpg not Bitmap... or you can tell me how to create the bitmap in c++ of a jpg image